# date changed when converting it from java.util.Date to javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, java.util.date, xmlgregoriancalendar

the Date Thu Sep 27 00:00:00 CEST 2018

becomes

2018-09-26T22:00:00.000Z

when converted in XMLGregorianCalendar

by this method:

```
 public static XMLGregorianCalendar dateToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException{
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
}
```

How can I avoid this date change?

Tnx

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I am in Europe/Copenhagen time zone, which uses CEST at this time of year, and I get `2018-09-27T00:00:00.000+02:00`. Is your time zone different? Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the same date & time.

Your first date is in timezone CEST, which is equivalent to UTC+2
Your second timestamp is rendered in Z timezone, which is equivalent to UTC+0

Thus, both mean the same point in time, but just render differently.

GregorianCalendar has a method to change the calendars timezone, if you want output in CEST date & time then I suggest you change the calendar timezone to that. See [GregorianCalendar.setTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) for API reference.

It also kind of depends on how you retrieve your date from that calendar. If you just plan to use the `.getTime()` method that returns a plain Java Date object, then you can send this through a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to output the date in whatever timezone you desire.

If you only care about the actual "date" part of the date, and don't want to adapt it to various timezones, have a look at [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a question with a number of possible answers depending on your circumstances and exact requirements. I am assuming that you are asking for an `XMLGregorianCalendar` because you are going to use it in an XML document where its `toXMLFormat` method produces the syntax you need.

### Try if a LocalDate works

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 27);
    System.out.println(ld);
```

This outputs:

> 2018-09-27

If what you need to put into your XML document is a date, not a date and time and UTC offset, this would be the logical solution. The above is a valid date format in XML (check the links at the bottom). Whether the receiver of your XML document accepts it I cannot tell. I’d find out if that were me.

The method in your question accepts a `Date` argument. The `Date` class is long outdated and has design problems, so avoid it if you can. If you cannot avoid it, convert it to `LocalDate` like this:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
    LocalDate ld = date.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
```

Please use your desired time zone where I put Europe/Rome since it is never the same date in all time zones. The correct time zone is what controls whether you get September 26 or 27.

### Use OffsetDateTime

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 27)
                            .atStartOfDay(zone)
                            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(odt);
```

> 2018-09-27T00:00+02:00

This is almost the syntax you also get from `XMLGregorianCalendar` (`XMLGregorianCalendar` could produce it too if you wanted). Seconds and milliseconds are not included. Again, check if it’s OK. If it isn’t, format your `OffsetDateTime` into a `String` for your XML:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx");
    String dateTimeString = odt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTimeString);
```

> 2018-09-27T00:00:00.000+02:00

This follows the syntax you got from `XMLGregorianCalendar` in your question exactly, only the date and time have not been changed. Again if you cannot avoid accepting an old-fashioned `Date`, convert:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = date.toInstant().atZone(zone).toOffsetDateTime();
```

### If you do need an XMLGregorianCalendar

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = date.toInstant().atZone(zone);
    GregorianCalendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlgcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
    System.out.println(xmlgcal);
```

> 2018-09-27T00:00:00.000+02:00

The specification of time zone controls the offset and thereby also the date and time produced.

### Links

- [XSD Date and Time Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp)
- [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition: section *date*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date)